# The page is shaking when scrolling down if use document.documentElement.scrollTop

Tags: javascript

First of all, I can only use vanilla javascript for the current project.
Run my codes below, there are 3 sections, I want to fix the second black section when it reached the top of the screen, but now the issue is if you use mouse wheel or touchpad scroll down the page, you will see the page is shaking.

I tried many ideas but can't fix this issue, hope anyone can give a solution or correct direction. Thanks!

```js
 window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
      var nextSection = document.querySelector('#next-section');
      var fixedSection = document.querySelector('#fixed-section');
      var doc = document.documentElement;
      
      //When scroll down
      if (doc.scrollTop >= nextSection.offsetTop - window.innerHeight) {
         doc.scrollTop = nextSection.offsetTop - window.innerHeight;
      }
 });
```

```css
.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  line-height: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#fixed-section {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="previous-section" class="section">Just scroll down</div>
<div id="fixed-section" class="section">Fix this section when it reached the top of the viewport.</div>
<div id="next-section" class="section"></div>
```

Comment: works fine on safari

Comment: @Rick It's shaking on chrome, firefox and opera